# sendmail/mailx and verbose mode not working the same

Tags: sendmail, postfix-mta, mailx

i have been running centOS-6 for some time now.  whenever i issue a mailx or sendmail command from the command line such as this:

```
echo 'Subject: testing'|sendmail -v mark@email.com -s this is a test';
```

i get a lot of good diagnostic messages such as:

```
this,is,a,test,-s,mark@domainname.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 domainname.info ESMTP Postfix
>>> EHLO domainname.info
250-domainname.info
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
```

however, on centOS-7 i am not seeing the same verbose messages, even with identical command lines.  all i am seeing is this:

```
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <edwardmark@email.com>.
```

in both servers (centOS-6 & 7) the email is indeed coming through successfully.

any suggestions will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First server (`Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay`) uses sendmail provided by sendmail.
Second server (`Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to ...`) uses sendmail provided by postfix - see [Debugging Postfix from inside](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#trace_mail).

You can use reports emailed by postfix or install sendmail instead of postfix.